# Why does IntelliJ delete my files when I do refactor? So I lost all my work

Tags: java, refactoring, intellij-idea

I did right-click > refactor > move from the project menu, "Move everything from .../../ to another directory" > OK selected a different folder, and wham, all my data is gone.
I did a grep -r in the project tree to find it, and a find . -iname '*mydataas*' still nothing shows up. Its gone.

Why does Intellij do this?

Comment: I've never had that happen in the six years I've been using IntelliJ.  Sounds like you screwed up.  I'd look outside the project and see where your files went.  I'd also ask why you aren't using Subversion or Git.  Your stuff wouldn't be gone if you had a version control system.

Comment: Surely you won't have lost all your work? Just since your last checkin... the rest will still be in your source control repository.

Comment: Just be happy that this didn't happen closer to a deadline :-)  Next time you just pick it out of your source code repository.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, that's never happened to me either.  Second, right-click on the original directory and select "Local History".  A history dialog should come up, which you can use to revert to what was there before you tried to refactor.

Comment: This was a new gwt module I was working on, so I didnt have it committed to svn, I was just about to comit it, just after moving it to the right directory.

Comment: Thank you Dave, it was in the "Local History", nowhere else, I was about to begin rewriting everything... thanks.

Comment: This happened to me: 1) Refactor > Rename a package 2) Drop new classes in renamed package 3) Subversion > Revert the package renaming ---> classes gone.  Checking local history on the _parent_ package of the renamed package did the trick.

Comment: I just had this happen to me as well. IntelliJ had actually moved the files into another class (instead of the package that I was aiming for). Just had to go into that class and Ctrl-Z (undo the move).